How to get Instagram media ID using POST URL by API, Currently I don't get particular media id
I want to get all likes, share and comments count of particular post using link via Instagram API
How I can resolve this?
I use almost every way but I can not find solution for this problem.
I use almost every way but I can not find solution for this problem

What solutions have you tried and what issues did you face?

Assuming you have the {post_id} (the media ID of the post), you should be able to make a GET request like this:
https://graph.instagram.com/{post_id}?fields=id,comments_count,like_count&access_token={access_token}
You can refer to the official docs to see an example of this, along with all possible fields you can read. (Notice that there is no "share count", as you mentioned in your question.
If you only have the post URL (permalink), you will not be able to use this API for your desired use-case.
